# how to submit text in searchview programmatically?

Tags: java, android

How can I submit text inside a SearchView programmatically?

I get text from previous activity and put it in the `SearchView` in the 2nd activity.

```
    // get text from previous activity
    schoolDbn = getIntent().getExtras().getString("dbn");

    final SearchView searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchID);


    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() 
     {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            myadapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            myadapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            return true;
        }
    });

    // sets text from first activity
    searchView.setQuery(schoolDbn, true);

    }
```

**SearchView XML**

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>
```

**What I want to happen** User clicks item in first activity and in 2nd activity SearchView auto submits text.

Comment: Your code is ok. Make sure `schoolDbn` is not null.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  ``schoolDbn`` is not null.  When I click the ``SearchView`` the text is inside.  I have to manually click enter to search.  I want to not need to click enter to search, I want it to click enter in ``SearchView`` programatically.

Comment: If you want to do search request in your secomd activity , after setting every code call `myadapter.getFilter().filter(s)` at very end so it gets call only once when activity is open. Make sure to put a null check on this call.

Comment: That is what I have done and nothing is submitted programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

When you clear focus from `searchView` the `onQueryTextSubmit(String s)` method not called. So remove this line `searchView.clearFocus();` after `setQuery();` and make sure set `setOnQueryTextListener` before `setQuery();`

And

For hiding keyboard when the `activity` starts use `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` in your `activity` tag in your `AndroidManifest`

Or

`getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN)‌​;` on your activity's onCreate method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I removed ``searchView.clearFocus(); after setQuery();`` but it still does not auto submit the text inside the ``SearchView``.

Comment: @Treewallie I Updated answer check it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I did what you said and ``setOnQueryTextListener before setQuery();`` but it still doesn't not auto submit the text in the ``SearchView``

Comment: @Treewallie You must call `setQuery();` after initializing all of your components such as adapter etc... and make sure your data is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have done that and updated the code of the post but still it still does not auto submit the text in the ``SearchView``